# Stringify JSON -> Python Server gets dict with key which is stringified string

Tags: python, json, string

```
var jsData = {
    id:         'E1',
    firstname:  'Peter',
    lastname:   'Funny',
    project: { id: 'P1' },
    activities: [
        { id: 'A1' },
        { id: 'A2' }
    ]};

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsData);


$('#click').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "test/",
        type: "POST",
        data: jsData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(){$('#text').html('FATAL_ERROR')}

    })
})
```

This is the JS-Code and jsData should be send to the Server(Python).
On the Server i get something like {'{id:'E1',firstname:'Peter',lastname:'Funny',project: { id: 'P1' },activities: [{ id: 'A1' },{ id: 'A2' }]};':''}

Is there a smart way to get the string 'inner dict' out of the 'outer dict' ?!

Comment: I don't know which framework you are using on the server side but you should be able to access something like `request.body` and get the data. By the way - when you are using `dataType` is the type you are expecting back from the server. You should use `contentType:"application/json"` to notify the server about the type of the data in your request.

Answer (score 11):

Python has a built-in JSON parsing library. Adding `import json` provides basic JSON parsing functionality, which can be used as follows:

```
import json
personString = "{'{id:'E1',firstname:'Peter',... " # This would contain your JSON string
person = json.loads( personString ) # This will parse the string into a native Python dictionary, be sure to add some error handling should a parsing error occur

person['firstname'] # Yields 'Peter'
person['activities'] # Yields a list with the activities.
```

More information here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: json.loads will throw " Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes" since personString is not a valid json because of `single quotes`.

Comment: The JSON in the example will not parse at all, as the ellipses I added make it invalid JSON. This is clearly an example string.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the wrong variable!

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsData);
..
$.ajax({
      ..,
      contentType: "application/json", //Remember to set this.
      data: jsData,
            ^^^^^^ => Shouldn't you be passing "jsonData" here?
```

When you pass a simple javascript dictionary, jQuery encodes the keys and values in the percentile-encoding format. That is the reason why you are seeing the inner dict as string.

What you have to do ideally (IMO), is pass the JSON string rather than partially percentile encoded string.

Note that you will probably have to change the way your server is reading the data. In this way there would no longer be HTTP/POST request parameters. Just a plain JSON string in the HTTP entity section.

Comment: Right that is a mistake ich tested it with both variables ! and both seems to work fine.
contentType: "application/json" causes that i get an empty dict on the Server

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test/",
        type: "POST",
        data: jsData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(){$('#text').html('FATAL_ERROR')}

    })
})
```

with this

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"jsData": jsData },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(){$('#text').html('FATAL_ERROR')}

    })
})
```

So that now you'll be able to get the jsData in the request.POST.get('jsData') or requst.GET.get('jsData') and you just need to parse the data that you get in the jsData key.

And you're good to go.